# How in mysql do I select a specific column followed by all columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for something that would produce the output I expect from

`SELECT COLUMN2, * FROM TABLE` (this though returns a syntax error)

After this I would expect to see the same output as `SELECT *` but with COLUMN2 returned first.

Comment: And that expected output would be? Your example will give you what you expect, unless you do not wish to see COLUMN2 twice.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575015/how-do-i-select-columns-by-their-numeric-position-in-a-table

Comment: If OP leaves just `*` then he'll get a syntax error from MySql

Comment: -1 for expecting telepathy from the rest of us.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness, still learning how best to phrase questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT column2 new_name, t.*
  FROM table_name t
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks.